# How do I separate a JSON file to individual JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON File that has data similar to this:

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

What I want to do is separate the JSON file programmatically in python so that a new file would contain the objects individually without being in one JSON array Like so:

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"} 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"} 
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
```

Basically removing all the commas between objects and the square brackets.

Comment: But then the file isn't valid JSON. What are you actually trying to achieve with this? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: So the reason why I am doing this is because I am trying to load data into amazon redshift using the json auto function that's built into it. However I found (maybe I am incorrect in the way that I am going about this) that redshift throws an error when I give it a valid json file. However if the objects are separated as I mentioned above, it is able to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read in and parse the JSON into a Python array of objects [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)
2. Iterate over this array and for each object:
   a) Serialize to json [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps)
   b) Write to file
   c) Write newline

Comment: @harcot could you have a go at writing it yourself?

Comment: Sure, I tried a few things before that didn't work. Here is what I came up with after reading @xbonez answer

`target = open('file','w')
with open('jsonfile') as jsondata:
    jsondata = json.load(jsondata)
    for data in jsondata:
        serial = json.dumps(data)
        target.write(serial)
    target.close()`